# Can a weak entity have subclasses

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I would like to know if a weak entity have sub-classes.
It seem that I can't find any rules that mention it cannot be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF weak entity is not in normalization then we can not divide it in sub classes.
Because weak entity itself depends on 1 or 2 entities.so it does not contains normalize-able attributes.